# That light is bothering my eyes

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

If the light is turned on, and a person is trying to sleep,he asks the other person to turn off the light.
Will it be natural to use:

> That light is bothering my eyes.

Is there a more natural way to describe this?

And a light that  is very bright, is flashed into someone's eyes or flashes into someone's eyes, what will be a natural way to describe it:

> This light is so bright that it is bothering my eyes.

I couldn't think of a natural way to describe this. So in any of such sentences, how is it described by the natives?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ced but I would not think it strange if someone said, "That light is bothering my eyes."

Comment: Are there other ways to express it as well?( More natural way). Like that light enters your eyes and stains the eyes.

Comment: @It's about English - I don't know what you mean when you say light stains someone's eyes. Could you explain? Do you mean the eyes change colour?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather say

> That light is bothering me.
>
> This light annoys me.

You don't need to say "bothering my eyes" as the person who is bothered by the light is you and not your eyes.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to it? @Ced

Comment: Of course there are always alternatives to everything.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you might just say:

> Can you turn the light off? I am trying to sleep!

It is pretty obvious what the connection is. It doesn't need to be explicitly stated.